# How to pause/resume the video recording

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I want to implement pause/resume functionality while recording video. MediaRecorder is not having any method for pause/resume. Native camera application is having pause/resume feature. Is it possible to implement it?

Please guide me. Any help or guidance will be well appreciated.